# "The 'qiskit-aer' library is required to use 'Aer provider'

Tags: qiskit

`code`
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit,ClassicalRegister,QuantumRegister
qr=QuantumRegister(3)
cr=ClassicalRegister(3)
qc=QuantumCircuit(qr,cr)
qc.x(qr[0])
qc.y(qr[1])
qc.z(qr[2])
qc.measure(qr,range(3))
print(qc.draw())
import qiskit
backend=qiskit.Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
job=qiskit.execute(qc,backend,shorts=1024)
results=job.result()
counts=results.get_counts(qc)
print(counts)

`Error`
`'File "C:\Users\HPC\Desktop\python_til\QISKIT\q4.py", line 11, in <module> backend=qiskit.Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator') ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\qiskit\__init__.py", line 134, in __getattr__ raise MissingOptionalLibraryError( qiskit.exceptions.MissingOptionalLibraryError: "The 'qiskit-aer' library is required to use 'Aer provider'. You can install it with 'pip install qiskit-aer'."`'

I expected result but it getting error

Answer (score 0):

Qiskit Aer was moved from Qiskit into it's own package as per the message.

From [Qiskit 0.44 release notes](https://qiskit.org/documentation/release_notes.html#qiskit-0-44-0)

> The Qiskit Aer project is still active and maintained moving forward it is just no longer included as part of the qiskit package. To continue using qiskit-aer you will need to explicitly install qiskit-aer and import the package from qiskit_aer.

Maybe you did the `pip install qiskit-aer` but you need to change how Aer is imported so you do it from `qiskit_aer` not `qiskit` as follows:

```
import qiskit_aer
backend=qiskit_aer.Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
```

If you change those lines the code will run, ie this below, which is a lightly version of what you posted above, runs

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister, execute
qr=QuantumRegister(3)
cr=ClassicalRegister(3)
qc=QuantumCircuit(qr,cr)
qc.x(qr[0])
qc.y(qr[1])
qc.z(qr[2])
qc.measure(qr,range(3))
print(qc.draw())

from qiskit_aer import Aer
backend=Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
job=execute(qc,backend,shorts=1024)
results=job.result()
counts=results.get_counts(qc)
print(counts)
```

and produces

```
      ┌───┐┌─┐      
q0_0: ┤ X ├┤M├──────
      ├───┤└╥┘┌─┐   
q0_1: ┤ Y ├─╫─┤M├───
      ├───┤ ║ └╥┘┌─┐
q0_2: ┤ Z ├─╫──╫─┤M├
      └───┘ ║  ║ └╥┘
c0: 3/══════╩══╩══╩═
            0  1  2 
{'011': 1024}
```